# Where is the differentiation in the differential form

Tags: differential-geometry

I do understand what a differential 1-form does.  But I don't understand where the differentiation is.  Why are differential 1 forms (or even k -forms) named the way they are.

Also a general differentiation of the term 'form' would be useful

Comment: Very rough answer: differential $1$-forms capture what happens when you make small changes. That's what derivatives do, hence the name. In actual calculations with $1$-forms you differentiate.

Comment: I am puzzled by you saying that "I don't understand where the differentiation is".  Given a function f the corresponding differential form is $df= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$.  **That's** where the derivative is.

Answer (score 1):

*Differential forms* are so named because they are built from differentials. 
The word *differential* [is related to](https://www.etymonline.com/word/differential) *difference*. As you probably knows, differentials, like $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ are often thought of as infinitessimally small differences. That's the origin of Leibniz's notation for derivatives:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \lim \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

Thus, the name *differential form* isn't directly related to differentiation. That said, a multivariable function $f$ is said to be *differentiable* at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $J$ such that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-Jh\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$
It can be shown that the action of $J$ on $h=(h^i)$ is given by 
$$Jh = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} h^i.$$

On a differential $p$-form $\omega = f \, \mathrm{d}x^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_p}$ the *exterior derivative* $\mathrm{d}$ is defined by
$$\mathrm{d}\omega = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}  \, dx^j \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_p}.$$

For a $0$-form $f$, which just is a function, we get
$$\mathrm{d}f = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \mathrm{d}x_i.$$
Comparing this with the expression for $Jh$ we see that we can identify $J$ with the exterior derivative or differential $\mathrm{d}f.$ Thus, *differentiability* and *differentials* are closely related concepts.

---

Regarding the word *form* I haven't seen any general definition. But it seems to be used when some abstract expressions are constructed, perhaps without having a precise concrete definition. For example, a differential form is a construction of the form (pun intended) $f \, \mathrm{d}x^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_p}$. You can come a long way just working with them in this abstract form without having a formal definition as a [quotient algebra of tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Formal_definitions_and_algebraic_properties) of linear maps.

Comment: I believe the "form" comes from the algebra terminology: linear, quadratic, bilinear, multilinear forms.

Comment: "Thus, the name differential form isn't directly related to differentiation"    Thanks, that's exactly what was confusing me about the term.  I figured I was missing something.    Also your comment about the term form was helpful -- unlike most things in mathematics the term 'form' isn't explicitly defined, but like most ordinary language, defined by usage.